How do I use a nodejs module in a reactjs application?
I am trying to make a youtube video downloader app using react and I have found an npm package called ytdl-core to do so, how do I use the npm package in my react app?
I created my react app with an input tag to paste the url of the video which is to be downloaded and extracted the input value and now I have to pass this url to node module
import React, {useState} from 'react'

function Input() {
  const [url, setUrl] = useState("");
  const downloadVideo = () => {
    const downloadURL= url;
  }
  return (
    <div className="p-4">
      <h1 className="text-3xl font-bold mb-4">Youtube Video Downloader</h1>
      <input
        type="text"
        onChange={(e) => setUrl(e.target.value)}
        className="border border-gray-300 rounded px-3 py-2 w-full mb-4"
        placeholder="Enter video URL"
        />
      <button
        onClick={() => downloadVideo()}
        className="bg-blue-500 text-white px-4 py-2 rounded hover:bg-blue-600"
      >
        Download
      </button>
    </div>
  
  )
}

export default Input


You can't. The package you found is a node.js package, i.e., it runs on the back-end, not in the browser. You can tell because of:
const fs = require('fs');

i.e., it uses the fs (file system) package, which doesn't work in the browser.
You'll need to create a node.js server, have your front-end react application send that server the link you want to download, and then use the package you found in that back-end server.
